# Menu is not dropping down after user come back to the top of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

On my website I've got a sticky, dropdown menu. When page is already loaded (without scrolling) or after user page scrolling there's everything ok - menu is dropping down.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('li').hover(function(){
$(this).find('ul>li').stop().slideToggle(250);
});
});


$(function () {
    var stickyHeaderTop = $('#navigationwrap').offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop) {
            $('#navigationwrap').css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: '0px'
            });
            $('#contentwrap').css('margin-top', $('#navigationwrap').outerHeight(true) + parseInt($('#headerwrap').css('marginBottom')));
        } else {
            $('#navigationwrap').css({
                position: 'static',
                top: '0px'
            });
            $('#contentwrap').css('margin-top', '0px');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #333;
}

p {
    padding: 10px;
}

#navigation ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: auto;
 list-style-type: none;
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
}

#navigation {
 text-align: center;
}

#navigation ul li {
 float: left;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 40px;
 text-align: center;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
 width: 140px;
}

#navigation ul li:hover {
 background: #9D9FA4;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

ul li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}

ul li li {
 background: #3F61A9;
 color: #fff;
 display: none;
}

ul li li:hover {
 background: #9D9FA4;
}

ul li li a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
}


#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
}

#headerwrap {
    width: 1000px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative; 
}

#header {
    height: 125px;
    background: #000000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    margin: 5px;
 position: relative;
}

#navigationwrap {
    width: 1000px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
}

#navigation {
    height: 40px;
    background: #52bf6e;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #3ea858;
    margin: 5px;
}

#contentwrap {
    width: 700px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#content {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
}

#leftcolumnwrap {
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#leftcolumn {
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
}

#rightcolumnwrap {
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#rightcolumn {
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
}

#footerwrap {
    width: 1000px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear: both;
}

#footer {
    height: 40px;
    background: #9D9FA4;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #888a91;
    margin: 5px;
 background-color: #9D9FA4;
 text-align: center;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#navigationwrap_placeholder {
    display:none;
 height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="headerwrap">
        <div id="header">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="navigationwrap">
        <div id="navigation">
   <ul>
   <li><a href="">main menu</a></li>
   <li><a>test</a>
   <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="">test1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">test2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">test3</a></li>
    <li><a href="">test4</a></li>
   </ul>
   </li>
   </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
  <div id="navigationwrap_placeholder"></div>
        <div id="leftcolumnwrap">
        <div id="leftcolumn">
            <p></p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="contentwrap">
        <div id="content">
   <br><br>
<p>Sed lacinia, urna non tincidunt mattis, tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc feugiat mi a tellus consequat imperdiet. Vestibulum sapien. Proin quam. Etiam ultrices. Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit. Sed lectus. Integer euismod lacus luctus magna. Quisque cursus, metus vitae pharetra auctor, sem massa mattis sem, at interdum magna augue eget diam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi lacinia molestie dui. Praesent blandit dolor. </p>
               <p>Sed non quam. In vel mi sit amet augue congue elementum. Morbi in ipsum sit amet pede facilisis laoreet. Donec lacus nunc, viverra nec, blandit vel, egestas et, augue. Vestibulum tincidunt malesuada tellus. Ut ultrices ultrices enim. Curabitur sit amet mauris. Morbi in dui quis est pulvinar ullamcorper. Nulla facilisi. Integer lacinia sollicitudin massa. Cras metus. Sed aliquet risus a tortor. Integer id quam. </p>
   <br><br>
  </div>
        </div>
        <div id="rightcolumnwrap">
        <div id="rightcolumn">
            <p></p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footerwrap">
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is when user comes back to the top of the page. Then menu is not dropping down. I have got two JS scripts. One allows to drop down the menu, the other one causes that the menu is sticked to the top of the page after user scrolling.

I found out that when I remove #content and #contentwrap from CSS, then menu is dropping down, but it appears behind the text. However, I wouldn't like to remove it.

Also, when I hover over ul > li > a called 'test' it moves to right a little. I would like to get rid of it.

What should I add or delete so as menu would work properly no matter where menu is displayed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the `position` to `relative` instead of `static` when you are scrolling up.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('li').hover(function(){
$(this).find('ul>li').stop().slideToggle(250);
});
});


$(function () {
    var stickyHeaderTop = $('#navigationwrap').offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop) {
            $('#navigationwrap').css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: '0px'
            });
            $('#contentwrap').css('margin-top', $('#navigationwrap').outerHeight(true) + parseInt($('#headerwrap').css('marginBottom')));
        } else {
            $('#navigationwrap').css({
                position: 'relative',
                top: '0px'
            });
            $('#contentwrap').css('margin-top', '0px');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #333;
}

p {
    padding: 10px;
}

#navigation ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: auto;
 list-style-type: none;
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
}

#navigation {
 text-align: center;
}

#navigation ul li {
 float: left;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 40px;
 text-align: center;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
 width: 140px;
}

#navigation ul li:hover {
 background: #9D9FA4;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

ul li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}

ul li li {
 background: #3F61A9;
 color: #fff;
 display: none;
}

ul li li:hover {
 background: #9D9FA4;
}

ul li li a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
}


#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
}

#headerwrap {
    width: 1000px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative; 
}

#header {
    height: 125px;
    background: #000000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    margin: 5px;
 position: relative;
}

#navigationwrap {
    width: 1000px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
}

#navigation {
    height: 40px;
    background: #52bf6e;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #3ea858;
    margin: 5px;
}

#contentwrap {
    width: 700px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#content {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
}

#leftcolumnwrap {
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#leftcolumn {
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
}

#rightcolumnwrap {
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#rightcolumn {
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
}

#footerwrap {
    width: 1000px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear: both;
}

#footer {
    height: 40px;
    background: #9D9FA4;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #888a91;
    margin: 5px;
 background-color: #9D9FA4;
 text-align: center;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#navigationwrap_placeholder {
    display:none;
 height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="headerwrap">
        <div id="header">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="navigationwrap">
        <div id="navigation">
   <ul>
   <li><a href="">main menu</a></li>
   <li><a>test</a>
   <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="">test1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">test2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">test3</a></li>
    <li><a href="">test4</a></li>
   </ul>
   </li>
   </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
  <div id="navigationwrap_placeholder"></div>
        <div id="leftcolumnwrap">
        <div id="leftcolumn">
            <p></p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="contentwrap">
        <div id="content">
   <br><br>
<p>Sed lacinia, urna non tincidunt mattis, tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc feugiat mi a tellus consequat imperdiet. Vestibulum sapien. Proin quam. Etiam ultrices. Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit. Sed lectus. Integer euismod lacus luctus magna. Quisque cursus, metus vitae pharetra auctor, sem massa mattis sem, at interdum magna augue eget diam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi lacinia molestie dui. Praesent blandit dolor. </p>
   <p>Sed non quam. In vel mi sit amet augue congue elementum. Morbi in ipsum sit amet pede facilisis laoreet. Donec lacus nunc, viverra nec, blandit vel, egestas et, augue. Vestibulum tincidunt malesuada tellus. Ut ultrices ultrices enim. Curabitur sit amet mauris. Morbi in dui quis est pulvinar ullamcorper. Nulla facilisi. Integer lacinia sollicitudin massa. Cras metus. Sed aliquet risus a tortor. Integer id quam. </p>
         <p>Sed non quam. In vel mi sit amet augue congue elementum. Morbi in ipsum sit amet pede facilisis laoreet. Donec lacus nunc, viverra nec, blandit vel, egestas et, augue. Vestibulum tincidunt malesuada tellus. Ut ultrices ultrices enim. Curabitur sit amet mauris. Morbi in dui quis est pulvinar ullamcorper. Nulla facilisi. Integer lacinia sollicitudin massa. Cras metus. Sed aliquet risus a tortor. Integer id quam. </p>
               <p>Sed non quam. In vel mi sit amet augue congue elementum. Morbi in ipsum sit amet pede facilisis laoreet. Donec lacus nunc, viverra nec, blandit vel, egestas et, augue. Vestibulum tincidunt malesuada tellus. Ut ultrices ultrices enim. Curabitur sit amet mauris. Morbi in dui quis est pulvinar ullamcorper. Nulla facilisi. Integer lacinia sollicitudin massa. Cras metus. Sed aliquet risus a tortor. Integer id quam. </p>
   <br><br>
  </div>
        </div>
        <div id="rightcolumnwrap">
        <div id="rightcolumn">
            <p></p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footerwrap">
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works.. If someone know how to stop moving the text when I hover a mouse over drop down element, it would be great.. Also, looking for a solution for my footer so as it would be displayed on the bottom of the screen when there is not enough content..